# Fastest way to convert a List<Type> to List<OtherType>

Tags: java, list, collections, addition

Imagine we have the following code

```
private List<String> convertScreenTypeToString(List<ScreenType> screenTypeList){
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for(ScreenType screenType : screenTypeList){
            result.add(screenType.getLabel());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But, we got different Type (ScreenType, HomeType, UserType) and I dont want to repeat the same method 3 times more and I cant use inheritance because they are a providen model. (Arch design stuff).

Also,

```
.... TypeToScreen(List<Object> whatever){}
```

It is not a proper solution.

And furthermore:

```
private class Convert<T>{ .....TypeToScreen(List<T> whatecer){}}
```

Inside the parent class is OK but i am searching for some advanced ways

Comment: title: "covert" or "convert"?

Comment: Convert** Jajajaja i missclicked the n. Where can i change it?

Comment: In the title?! Can't your browser do string search? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams will let you map elements of a list.

```
List<String> labels =
    screenTypes.stream()
        .map(ScreenType::getLabel)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There's no guarantees as to what sort of `List` that is, so you might want to wrap in `new ArrayList<>()` or similar.

It's be convenient if there was a method like this on `List`. You can write a convenience method for this very common case.

```
public static <T, R> List<R> map(
    List<T> source, Function<? super T,​ ? extends R> mapping
) {
    return
        screenTypes.stream()
            .map(mapping)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll);
}
```

Here the three-argument form of `Stream.collect` removes the need for an intermediate `List`. @Ousmane D. in the comments offers an alternative last line.

```
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Alternatively, you could write it out without streams. This is faster and easier to read, if either of those things matter to you.

```
public static <T, R> List<R> map(
    List<T> source, Function<? super T,​ ? extends R> mapping
) {
    List<R> result = new ArrayList<>(source.size());
    for (T t : source) {
        result.add(mapping.apply(t));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: "_There's no guarantees as to what sort of List that is, so you might want to wrap in new ArrayList<>() or similar_", you can go around that by using [`.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-)